# How to fill 100% of height and width of Ant Card?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, antd, ant-design-pro, styled-jsx

I am trying to fill 100% of ANT card height but when I use height 100% for a child it collapses.
Does anyone know how it's possible to do?
I know for sure that ant Card isn't equal to 0% because its parent has height and width

```html
<Card style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', background: 'red'}} headStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#E6ECF0', }} bodyStyle={{padding: 0}} type="inner">
  <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
  </div>
</Card>
```

Comment: what is the width and height of Card's parent? and what should be the content inside last DIV?

Comment: the heigth of card parent is 72vh and width 100 vw
And in content of last div should be  column with textfields and checkboxes.
I just simplified code to make question more clear.
I don't understand why i child can't use 100% height of Card like with regular divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent collapsing you should add `padding` to your card and use `box-sizing: border-box`;

```
<Card style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%', background: 'red', box-sizing:  'border-box'}} headStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#E6ECF0', }} bodyStyle={{padding: '5px'}} type="inner">
  <div style={{height: '100%', width: '100%'}}>
  </div>
</Card>
```

Comment: Thank you so much) Your answer really helped me.